# pointer being realloc'd was not allocated char* realloc in function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, realloc

I am learning pointers now, and i have some troubles with reallocating of char* in function. 
When i am running this code, i have this error. 
p.s. the one only goal of this code, it to understand how are pointers working.

```
void redefine(char** string) {
   *string = realloc(*string, 10 * sizeof(char));
   *string = "otherText";
}

int main(){
   char *first = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
   first = "text";
   redefine(&first);
   return 0;
}
```

thanks in forward

Comment: Good job not casting the return value from malloc().  Some may point out that sizeof(char) is not really needed, since chars have a size of 1, but I actually prefer something more like (sizeof(*first)).  This figures out what your pointer is pointing to and uses the sizeof that.  This guarantees that you use the correct datatype and even allows you to change the pointer type later without having to remember to change the malloc size.

Comment: @StephenDocy thanks for the feedback. good to know !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C doesn't use assignment to copy strings.

When you do

```
first = "text";
```

`first` now points to the literal string `text`, it no longer points to the memory that was allocated with `malloc()`. So you can't call `realloc()` on that pointer.

You should use:

```
strcpy(first, "text");
```

to copy the sdtring into the allocated memory.

Similarly, in the function you should use

```
strcpy(*string, "otherText");
```

Comment: Next topic for discussion: why you shouldn't actually use `strcpy`, like, ever.

Comment: @zwol as i wrote above, it's just for learning. so, i want to have a good understanding of how pointers are really work :)